# what is the different between (myVar && { myVar }) and { myVar }

Tags: javascript, object

I have seen few JavaScript repositories online where an object is created in the following syntax

```js
const myVar

const myObj = (myVar && {myVar})
```

I'm wondering why do we need to use this syntax, when the same output can be acheived by simply declaring the object like this:

```js
const myObj = {myVar}
```

Is there any difference between those two?

Comment: start with `const myVar = 0` and find out.

Comment: Well the point is that it *doesn't* always create an object

Comment: That makes no sense with `myVar` declared as `const`. It's only useful if you can change the value of `myVar` before assigning to `myObj`.

Comment: `const myObj = (myVar && {myVar})` it's a shorthand for  `const myObj = myVar ?  { myVar } :  myVar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with `&&` only creates the object if the value of `myVar` isn't falsey. If it's falsey, it will get the value of `myVar` as it is, not wrapped in an object.

Compare these examples:

```js
let myVar1 = 10;
let myObj1_and = (myVar1 && {myVar1});
let myObj1_noand = {myVar1};
console.log(myObj1_and);
console.log(myObj1_noand);

let myVar2 = 0;
let myObj2_and = (myVar2 && {myVar2});
let myObj2_noand = {myVar2};
console.log(myObj2_and);
console.log(myObj2_noand);
```

Without the `&&`, it creates the object regardless of the value of the variable.

Comment: Worth mentioning that myObj will get the value directly from myVar if it is falsey. So they could end up with myObj=false, myObj=0, myObj=undefined...